# How to send AWS SES email to same domain that is verified

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have setup Amazon Simple Email Service account on one my my domains. Lets say it example.com

I am not able to send emails to that same domain I have verified.

meaning sending email from noreply@example.com to myemail@example.com is not happening.

I even tried in AWS console's send test email but couldn't send the email.

I couldn't find in AWS SES documentation saying we can't send emails to same domain.

Can we send emails to same domain in AWS SES? If not is it documented in AWS SES?
If yes how can I send them?

Comment: There is no restriction on who you can email to except when you are still in sandbox mode, but even in that case you can send to a verified domain (or email address). Are you saying you can't send because you aren't getting the emails? Have you looked at your sending statistics?

Comment: Are you out of the Sandbox?

Comment: No I'm using live. but I found whats going wrong. I will answer in the answer section

Answer (score 1):

I don't see in AWS SES documentation that it doesn't support sending to the same domain name.

I finally got to know that the domain I'm using is configured with Office 365 email provider, the admin have configured Spam filters such a way that it doesn't even enter user's inbox if they recognized it to be sending automated emails from same domain.

Conclusion: its not an issue from Amazon AWS SES but in-house spam filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue and found the destination email had been added to AWS SES's suppression list because of a bounce reply from that email at some point. I'm not sure why it originally bounced, but after removing the email from the suppression list, email sending worked as expected again.

Link to suppression list:

> https://`<YOUR_REGION_CODE>`.console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=`<YOUR_REGION_CODE>`#/suppression-list